# Get id from url for referral

Tags: php, cookies

i have a referral system in my website, but i have problem the referral link is `website.com/?i=ID` but when they register the script that i use make this ID always to be 1, never take the correct number... I use this code:

```
$referer_id = (isset($_COOKIE["i"]) AND intval($_COOKIE["i"]) > 0 AND intval($_COOKIE["i"]) < 1000000) ? intval($_COOKIE["i"]) : 1;
if($referer_id != 1){

    $db->Query("SELECT user FROM db_users_a WHERE id = '$referer_id' LIMIT 1");

    if($db->NumRows() > 0){

        $referer_name = $db->FetchRow();

    }else{ $referer_id = 1; $referer_name = "Admin"; }

}else{ $referer_id = 1; $referer_name = "Admin"; }
```

Every time no matter what number i put on ID `website.com/?i=10` it will take it as 1... What can be the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

URL parameters are put in `$_GET`. So `$_COOKIE['i']` should be `$_GET['i']`. So it should be:

```
$referer_id = (isset($_GET['i']) && intval($_GET['i']) > 0 && intval($_GET['i']) < 1000000) ? intval($_GET['i']) : 1;
```

Comment: What do you mean by _referral link_? Is that the URL of the page that's linking to your page, not the URL of your page?

Comment: This is a unique url for every user, if you register under this link with the id of the user you become his referral but the problem is that no matter what id is after ?i= the code take it as number 1...... This is my problem it never take the correct number always take number 1

Comment: WHAT DOES `var_dump($_GET)` SHOW?

Comment: Uhm of you make it http://example.org/?id=2 $_GET['id'] will output 2. There is no doubt

Comment: how can i check it? i dont show nothing after this query just insert into mysql....

Comment: If `$_GET['i']` shows the correct value, I can't see any reason why it wouldn't set `$referer_id` to that. You must have a mistake in your code. I've updated my answer with the exact line you should use, try copying it.

Comment: man i try to make it like this $referer_id = $_GET['i'];
BUT referer_id become 1 every single time no matter what number you put on i referer_id always take it as 1........

Comment: Is it `id=` or `i=`? You said `$_GET['id']` outputs `2`, so that means it's `id=`.

Comment: This is why I wanted you to put `var_dump($_GET)` in your script and show the output.

Comment: If you don't know how to do simple debugging, we'll be here all night.

Comment: i, id doesn't matter i mean this is not wrong id or i it's i everywhere i put i.... this is not a mistake... check the code again speacialy this:
if($referer_id != 1){

    $db->Query("SELECT user FROM db_users_a WHERE id = '$referer_id' LIMIT 1");

    if($db->NumRows() > 0){

        $referer_name = $db->FetchRow();

    }else{ $referer_id = 1; $referer_name = "Admin"; }

}else{ $referer_id = 1; $referer_name = "Admin"; }

Here : if($referer_id != 1){   always give it to 1 everytime make query as 1

Comment: There's nothing helpful in that code. Either you show the output of `var_dump($_GET)` or stop bothering me.

Comment: if i make it var_dump($_GET) i get this error 
array(1) { ["menu"]=> string(6) "signup" }
if i make it var_dump($_GET['i']) i get this error
NULL

Comment: That means your page is being called with `?menu=signup`, not `?i=2`.

Comment: This is the rewrite
RewriteRule ^signup(/?)+$ index.php?menu=signup [L]

In the url my page is called example.org/signup

Comment: I don't really know much about rewrite rules. But I guess you need to fix the rule so it keeps the `i=` parameter in the URL.